# ES6 class method as Express router parameter

Tags: typescript, express, ecmascript-6, typeorm

I'm trying to pass a class method as an Express route parameter, i've tried binding the method and without using arrow function but it didn't work either.

I'm using TypeORM and the error i'm getting is this "Connection "default" was not found.", but if i write the complete function (like below) as the parameter everything works fine.

```
router.get("/", async (_req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
        const projects: Project[] = await new ProjectService().findAll();

        res.status(200).send(projects);
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(404).send(e.message);
    }
});
```

The code below doesn't work.

ProjectRoutes.ts

```
const router: Router = Router();

const projectController = new ProjectController();

router.get("/", projectController.getAllProjects);

export default router;
```

ProjectController.ts

```
export class ProjectController {
    projectService: ProjectService = new ProjectService();

    getAllProjects = async (_req: Request, res: Response) => {
        try {
            const projects: Project[] = await this.projectService.findAll();
            return res.status(200).send(projects);
        } catch (e) {
            return res.status(404).send(e.message);
        }
    };
}
```

ProjectService.ts

```
export class ProjectService {
    projectRepository: ProjectRepository;

    constructor() {
        this.projectRepository = getCustomRepository(ProjectRepository);
    }

    async findAll(): Promise<Project[]> {
        return await this.projectRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

ProjectRepository

```
@EntityRepository(Project)
export class ProjectRepository extends Repository<Project> {
    async findAll(): Promise<Project[]> {
        return await this.find();
    }
}
```

Routes index.ts

```
const router: Router = Router();

router.use("/projects", ProjectRoutes);

export default router;
```

Server.ts

```
app.use("/", router);
```

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: There should be no problem with the way you pass the instance method (class field initialised with arrow function) to the router. What exactly does not work?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: @GabrielSouza Have you checked out this? https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4010#issuecomment-502431460 Seems like something to do with the way you are calling findAll().

Comment: It works if i write the complete function inside the router.get, so i think TypeORM is not the problem, unless i'm missing something, but i don't know what could be

Answer (score 1):

Error `Connection "default" was not found.` thrown by `typeorm` usually indicates that you're trying to create a repository/use manager/get connection before connection with DB gets established.

The difference between function request handler vs class method handler in your case is that in the function handler you're kind of lazily initializing service  (when the server receives request) and in-class approach eagerly (before registering route - at the server startup phase).

```
const projectController = new ProjectController(); // <--- here you're creating an instance of controller which creates an instance of ProjectService which creates aninstance of ProjectRepository
router.get("/", projectController.getAllProjects);
```

I guess my recommendation would be to wait for the database connection to be established before constructing controllers or any classes that rely on `typeorm` stuff.

Comment: Instead of instantiating ProjectService one time in ProjectController i'm instantiating it in every method like this "await new ProjectService().findAll();", this way it works cause it only gets the service/repository when the route is set. My question now is if instantiating in every method can cause problems in the future, like performance for example.

Answer (score 0):

@elderapo has pointed out the issue. You can make use of the following pattern to solve the problem.

*ProjectController.ts*

```
export class ProjectController {
    projectService: ProjectService = new ProjectService();

    getAllProjects = async (_req: Request, res: Response) => {
        try {
            const projects: Project[] = await this.projectService.findAll();
            return res.status(200).send(projects);
        } catch (e) {
            return res.status(404).send(e.message);
        }
    };
}
```

*routes.ts*

```
import {ProjectController} from './controller/ProjectController'

export const Routes = [{
    method: "get",
    route: "/",
    controller: ProjectController,
    action: "getAllProjects"
}]
```

*index.ts*

```
import {Routes} from "./routes";
...
createConnection().then(async connection => {

    // create express app
    const app = express();
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    // register express routes from defined application routes
    Routes.forEach(route => {
        (app as any)[route.method](route.route, (req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) => {
            const result = (new (route.controller as any))[route.action](req, res, next);
            if (result instanceof Promise) {
                result.then(result => result !== null && result !== undefined ? res.send(result) : undefined);

            } else if (result !== null && result !== undefined) {
                res.json(result);
            }
        });
    });

    // setup express app here
    // ...

    // start express server
    app.listen(3000);
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

This is the pattern used in the starter project generated with `typeorm init --name NodeStarter --database postgres --express`